# DOm.Rect with Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, devtools

### What are some specific uses of dom. Rect or what can it be used for?

---

#### I want to use this API to select nodes in the DOM...`DOM.Rect`

Comment: [ Dom.Rect ]( https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#type-Rect )

Answer (score 0):

It's just a type that is used in the DOM to represent a rectangular region. It's not much used - you can see a list of places it is referenced in Chrome APIs here: https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?DOM.Rect. As you can see, it's not much. And you can't use it to select nodes.

Comment: I want to give a region or rectangle in HTML and find its largest container within that region. For example, if I find the tbody of table in the web page, how do I find thead up from the tBody container? Of course, this table is non-standard and may be implemented using a different UI library.

Comment: In the development process, puppeteer was introduced, but CDP was needed to implement some functions, so the above problems occurred. Thank you for your answer and look forward to your reply.